# Draw Marker On GoogleMap APIV2 while locationchange

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to implement tracker in which when user starts the app then app should trace his position and path should be drawn on googlemap api v2. how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this piece of code, even when location changes, it automatically refreshes:

```
mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Comment: thanks for answering but i want to draw the path where user travels from starting to end position(where user stops the application)